# Vue js: Vuetify server side Datatable search filter not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify for my datatable. Pagination and sort are working except the search filter. The response data from search filter is correct but the problem is its not rendering the response to my template. In [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/data-tables) docs theres only have for pagination and sort. I'm trying to implement the search function via server-side.

My User.vue

```
export default{
    data () {
    return {
      max25chars: (v) => v.length <= 25 || 'Input too long!',
      tmp: '',
      search: '',
      totalItems: 0,
      pagination: {
        rowsPerPage: 1,
        search: ''
      },
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'name',
          align: 'left'
        },
        {
          text: 'Email Add',
          sortable: true,
          value:'email',
          align: 'left'
        },
        {
          text: 'Roles',
          sortable: true,
          value:'roles_permissions',
          align: 'left'
        },
        {
          text: 'Date joined',
          sortable: true,
          value:'created_at',
          align: 'left'
        }
      ],
      items: [],
      loading: false,
      timer: null
    }
  },
  watch:{
    pagination:{
            handler(){
                this.getDataFromApi()
          .then(data => {
            const self = this;
            self.items = data.items;
            self.totalItems = data.total;
          })
            },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getDataFromApi()
        .then(data => {
            this.items = data.items;
        this.totalItems = data.total;
        });
  },
  methods:{
    getDataFromApi(search_val){
        this.loading = true;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
                const search = this.search;
        //console.log(search);
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){

          axios({
            url: '/prod/api/user_table',
            method:'post',
            data:{
              sortBy : sortBy,
              descending: descending,
              page : page,
              rowsPerPage : rowsPerPage,
              search_val : search
            }
          })
          .then(response=>{
            if(response.status == 200){

              let items = response.data.data;
              const total = response.data.totalRecords;
              this.loading = false;
              resolve({
                items,
                total
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(error=>{
            if(error.response){
              console.log(error.response);
            }
          })
        },1000);
      })
    },
    fetchDataFromApi(value){
        //console.log(value);
    }
  },
  created(){

  }
}
```

Here is my back end side using laravel

```
public function dataTable(Request $request){
    //return Datatable::eloquent(User::query())->make(true);
    $sortBy = $request->sortBy;
    $descending = $request->descending;
    $page = $request->page;
    $rowsPerPage = $request->rowsPerPage;
    $search_val = $request->search_val;

    //echo $rowsPerPage;
    if($descending){
        $orderedBy = 'desc';
    }else{
        $orderedBy = 'asc';
    }
    $start = ($page - 1) * $rowsPerPage;


    /*$totalRec = User::all();
    if(empty(trim($search_val))){
        $user = User::orderBy($sortBy,$orderedBy)->skip($start)->take($rowsPerPage)->get();
    }else{
        $user = User::where([

        ]);
    }*/

    $query = User::query();
    $column = ['name', 'email'];
    foreach ($column as $col) {
       $query->orWhere($col, 'LIKE','%'.$search_val.'%');
    }
    $query->orderBy($sortBy,$orderedBy)->skip($start)->take($rowsPerPage);
    $arr_items = [];
    foreach ($query->get()->toArray() as $shit => $v) {
        $arr_items['data'][] = array(
            'value' => $v['id'],
            'name' => $v['name'],
            'email' => $v['email'],
            'roles_permissions' => '',
            'created_at' => $v['created_at']
        );
    }
    $arr_items['totalRecords'] = User::count();
    return response()->json($arr_items);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is missing important part: the template where you define properties for `v-data-table`. There might be something wrong with the way you define the template.

Answer (score 19):

## server side search & sort of datatable in vuetify.js

If we need server side *search* and *sort* in **vuetify.js datatable**, we have to make some changes in vuejs part.

```
import {environment} from '../../environment';
export default {
    name: "Category",
    data() {
        return {
            categories: [],
            search: '',
            total: 0,
            loading: false,
            pagination: {},
            headers: [
                {text: 'ID', value: 'id'},
                {text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
                {text: 'Actions', value: 'name', sortable: false, align: 'center'}
            ],
            rowsPerPageItems: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        }
    },
    watch: {
        pagination {
            this.getCategoriesByPagination();
        },
        search() {
            this.getCategoriesByPagination();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCategoriesByPagination() {
            this.loading = true;
            // get by search keyword
            if (this.search) {
                axios.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/category-filter?query=${this.search}&page=${this.pagination.page}&per_page=${this.pagination.rowsPerPage}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.categories = res.data.data;
                        this.total = res.data.meta.total;
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
                    .finally(() => this.loading = false);
            }
            // get by sort option
            if (this.pagination.sortBy && !this.search) {
                const direction = this.pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                axios.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/category-order?direction=${direction}&sortBy=${this.pagination.sortBy}&page=${this.pagination.page}&per_page=${this.pagination.rowsPerPage}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.categories = res.data.data;
                        this.total = res.data.meta.total;
                    });
            } if(!this.search && !this.pagination.sortBy) {
                axios.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/category?page=${this.pagination.page}&per_page=${this.pagination.rowsPerPage}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.categories = res.data.data;
                        this.total = res.data.meta.total;
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
                    .finally(() => this.loading = false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> in **html** part

```
<v-text-field v-model="search"
              append-icon="search"
              label="Search"
              single-line
              hide-details
            ></v-text-field>

<v-data-table :headers="headers"
              :items="categories"
              :pagination.sync="pagination"
              :total-items="total"
              :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems"
              :loading="loading"
            ></v-data-table>
```

in **Laravel** part, i used `laravel scout` package.

> Controller

```
/**
 * Get category
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
 */
public function getAll()
{
    $per_page = empty(request('per_page')) ? 10 : (int)request('per_page');
    $categories = Category::latest()->paginate($per_page);
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}

/**
 * Get category by search results
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
 */
public function getBySearch()
{
    $per_page = empty(request('per_page')) ? 10 : (int)request('per_page');
    $categories = Category::search(request()->query('query'))->paginate($per_page);
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}

/**
 * Get category by sorting
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
 */
public function getByOrder()
{
    $per_page = empty(request('per_page')) ? 10 : (int)request('per_page');
    $direction = request()->query('direction');
    $sortBy = request()->query('sortBy');
    $categories = Category::orderBy($sortBy, $direction)->paginate($per_page);
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}
```

> Route

```
    Route::get('category', 'Api\CategoryController@getAll');
    Route::get('category-filter', 'Api\CategoryController@getBySearch');
    Route::get('category-order', 'Api\CategoryController@getByOrder');
```

> Model

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

    class Category extends Model
    {
       use Searchable;

       /**
         * Get the indexable data array for the model.
         *
         * @return array
         */
         public function toSearchableArray()
         {
            return [
               'name' => $this->name
            ];
         }
    }
```

Comment: Well, actually if you want to use server side search, then you shouldn't use the `search` property of `v-data-table`. The `search` property activates client side rendering, so your dataset gets filtered twice, on the server and then on the client (which may produce weird results). Otherwise the answer is fine. Whenever you want to run server side search you just submit a XHR request and update your `items` model with the filtered data you've acquired.

Comment: If i want to go previous page and next then what to do?

Comment: @ZiaurRahman We are watching `pagination` property here. When you go previous or next page, it will call your API automatically.

Answer (score 2):

To enable server-side search to work don't pass the search prop to v-data-table. Otherwise the datatable pagination and search are client side even if you pass the "totalItems" prop.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the search prop but the initial value needs to be null. I tried it first with an empty string and it didn't work, at least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <template>
      <div class="data-table">
        <v-data-table  :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="5"  :options.sync="options" :server-items-length="totalDesserts" :loading="loading" class="elevation-1" ></v-data-table>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { api } from '~/config'
    import Form from '~/mixins/form'

    export default {
      data: () => ({

        desserts_s: [],
        totalDesserts: 0,
        loading: true,
        options: {},

        headers: [
          { text: 'id', value: 'id' },
          { text: 'lastname', value: 'lastname' },
          { text: 'email', value: 'email' },
        ],
        desserts: [],
      }),


        watch: {
          options: {
            handler () {
              this.getDataFromApi()
                .then(data => {
                  this.desserts = data.items
                  this.totalDesserts = data.total
                })
            },
            deep: true,
          },
        },
        mounted () {
          this.getDataFromApi()
            .then(data => {
              this.desserts = data.items
              this.totalDesserts = data.total
            })
        },
            methods: {
          getDataFromApi () {
            this.loading = true
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options

             axios.get(api.path('test')+"?"+Object.keys(this.options).map(key => key + '=' + this.options[key]).join('&'))
                .then((response) => {
                  let items = response.data.users.data 
                  const total = response.data.users.total

                    console.log(response.data.users.data)

                  if (sortBy.length === 1 && sortDesc.length === 1) {
                    items = items.sort((a, b) => {
                      const sortA = a[sortBy[0]]
                      const sortB = b[sortBy[0]]

                      if (sortDesc[0]) {
                        if (sortA < sortB) return 1
                        if (sortA > sortB) return -1
                        return 0
                      } else {
                        if (sortA < sortB) return -1
                        if (sortA > sortB) return 1
                        return 0
                      }
                    })
                  }
                    this.loading = false
                    resolve({
                      items,
                      total,
                    })

                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
            })
          },
          getDesserts () {


          },
        },
      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **computed**

i'm using server pagination and search. you can inspect my code

```
<template>
<v-card flat>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="tableHead"
    :items="computedFormData.items"
    v-if="computedFormData && computedFormData.items"
    :mobile-breakpoint="820"
    v-model="selected"
    :show-select="true"
    :loading="loading"
    :form-data="formData"
    @update:page="getItemPerPage"
    @update:items-per-page="getItemPerPage2"
    :server-items-length="paginationTotal"
    :schema="schema"
    :search="search"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat color="white">
        <v-toolbar-title class="mr-4" v-if="addHeading">{{ addHeading }}</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</v-card>
</template>

<script>
import {mapMutations, mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'DataTable',
  components: { Button, Tab: () => import('@/components/Tabs'), Dialog: () => import('@/components/Dialog'), TableFormBuilder: () => import('@/components/Form/TableFormBuilder'), FormBuilder: () => import('@/components/Form/FormBuilder') },
  props: [
    'schema',
    'formData',
    'name',
    'itemsTab',
    'value',
    'headers',
    'title',
    'nodata',
    'addHeading',
    'confirmDeleteTabItem',
    'tableTitleOptionA',
    'tableTitleOptionB',
    'items'
  ],
  data: () => ({
    loading: false,
    selected: [],
    companyValid: true,
    customerValid: true,
    search: '',
    dialog: false,
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {},
    defaultItem: {}
  }),

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('Connection', ['getConnectionPending', 'getAddFirm', 'getUpdateFirm', 'getDeleteFirm', 'getMultipleDeleteFirm', 'getCompanies']),
    ...mapGetters('Pagination', ['getPage']),
    tableHead(){
      return this.headers.filter(s => s.show);
    },
    computedFormData: {
      get: function () {
        return this.$parent.formData
      },
      set: function () {
        return this.formData
      }
    },
    paginationTotal: {
      get: function () {
        return this.$parent.formData.totalLength
      }
    },
    tabItems: {
      get: function () {
        if(this.search!==''){
          return this.$parent.formData.items.filter(s => s.firmaAdi === this.search)
        }else{
          return this.$parent.formData.items
        }
      },
      set: function () {
        return this.items
      }
    },
    formTitle () {
      return this.editedIndex === -1
        ? this.tableTitleOptionA
        : this.tableTitleOptionB
    }
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions("Snackbar", ["setSnackbar"]),
    ...mapActions("Connection", ["addFirmCall", "updateFirmCall", "deleteFirmCall", "multipleDeleteCall", "companiesCall"]),
    ...mapMutations('Selected', ['setSelected']),
    ...mapMutations('Pagination', ['setPage']),
    getItemPerPage (pagination) {
      this.loading=true;
      this.setPage(pagination)
    },
    getItemPerPage2 (pagination) {
      this.loading=true;
      this.setPage(pagination)
    },
  },
    watch: {
      getConnectionPending(e){
        this.loading=e
      },
      dialog(val) {
        val || this.close();
      },
      search(e){
        this.companiesCall({ page: this.getPage, limit: 10, search: e});
      },
      selected(e){
        this.setSelected(e)
      }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

To late for answer, but I was looking for something similar to work with [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) this days and didn't found any examples / libs, so created something that worked:

1. Install `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~9.0"` (And follow the instructions on how to add `Provider, Facade, config`
2. We will need to change our controller to Support DataTables:

```php
use DataTables;
------
public function dataTable(Request $request){
    //one line of code for simple search /sort / pagination
    return DataTables::of(User::query())->make(true);
}
```

3. Next we will adjust our `Vuetify` component

#### Template

```html
<template>
    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :pagination.sync="pagination"
        :total-items="totalUsers" 
        :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems"
        :loading="loading"
    >
        <template v-slot:items="props">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <v-btn  :to="{ name: 'users.edit', params: { id: props.item.id }}">Edit</v-btn>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-results>
            <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
                Your search for "{{ searchQuery }}" found no results.
            </v-alert>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
```

#### JS

```js
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {

        data () {
            return {
                draw: 1,
                users: [],
                searchQuery: "",
                loading: true,
                pagination: {
                    descending: true,
                    page: 1,
                    rowsPerPage: 10,
                    sortBy: "id",
                    totalItems: 0
                },
                totalUsers: 0,
                rowsPerPageItems: [10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                columns:{},
                headers: [
                    { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false, searchable: false, width: '210px'},
                    { text: 'ID', value: 'id', name: 'id', sortable: true, searchable: true, width: '40px'},
                    { text: 'Name', value: 'name', name: 'name', sortable: true, searchable: true, width: '250px'},
                    { text: 'Email', value: 'email', sortable: true, searchable: true, width: '80px'},
                ],
                cancelSource: null
            }
        },

        watch: {

            //watcher to watch for order/pagination and search criteria.
            //
            params: {
                handler() {
                    
                    //on params change refetch Data
                    //We don't do it in mounted method, becuase on first load params will change.
                    this.getDataFromApi().then(data => {

                        this.users = data.items;
                        this.totalUsers = data.total;
                        
                    });
                },

                deep: true
            }
        },

        mounted() {

            //Based on our Headers we create query data for DataTables
            //I've added a new param "searchable" to let DataBales know that this column is not searchable
            //You can also set name as "table.column eg users.name" if you select from more then table to avoid "Ambitious column name error from SQL"
            for (var i = 0; i < this.headers.length; i++) {

                this.columns[i] = {
                    data: this.headers[i].value,
                    name: (typeof(this.headers[i].name) != 'undefined' ? this.headers[i].name : this.headers[i].value),
                    searchable: this.headers[i].searchable,
                    orderable: this.headers[i].sortable,
                    search: {
                        value: '',
                        regex: false
                    }
                };
            }
        },

        //computed params to return pagination and search criteria
        computed: {
            params(nv) {

                return {
                    ...this.pagination,
                    query: this.searchQuery
                };
            }
        },

        methods: {

            cancelRequest() {

                //Axios cancelSource to stop current search if new value is entered
                if (this.cancelSource) {
                    this.cancelSource.cancel('Start new search, stop active search');
                }
            },

            getDataFromApi() {

                //show loading of Vuetify Table
                this.loading = true;

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                    this.cancelRequest();

                    this.cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

                    //copy current params to modify
                    let params = this.params;

                    params.length = params.rowsPerPage; //set how many records to fecth per page
                    params.start = params.page == 1 ? 0 : (params.rowsPerPage * (params.page - 1)); //set offset
                    params.search = {
                        value: params.query,
                        regex: false
                    }; //our search query

                    params.draw = this.draw;

                    //sorting and default to column 1 (ID)
                    if(params.sortBy){

                        params.order = {
                            0: {
                                column: _.findIndex(this.headers, {
                                    'value': params.sortBy
                                }),
                                dir: (params.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc')
                            }
                        };
                    }else{
                        params.order = {
                            0: {
                                column: 1,
                                dir: 'desc'
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    params.columns = this.columns; //set our previously created columns

                    //fecth data
                    //I used here jQuery $.param() helper, becuase axios submits data as JSON Payload, and we need for data or Query params
                    //This can be changed
                    axios.get('/users?'+$.param(params), {
                        cancelToken: this.cancelSource.token
                    }).then((res) => {

                        this.draw++;

                        this.cancelSource = null;

                        let items = res.data.data;
                        let total = res.data.recordsFiltered;

                        resolve({
                            items,
                            total
                        });

                    }).catch((err) => {
                        if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
                            console.log('Request canceled', err.message);
                        } else {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                    }).always(() => {
                        this.loading = false;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### Conclusion

A simple solution to make vuetify work with Laravel DataTables, for sure is not ideal, but works well. Hope this helped.